# Removing repeating elements in a sorted list

Tags: java, list, iteration

How can I remove a duplicate element in a sorted list while iterating?

I have a sorted list(not array) of objects, say:

```
apple
apple
pear
pear
pear
peach
```

I am currently using a 'for' loop with the Iterator function on my list.

```
for(ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();iter.hasNext();) {
  String it = iter.next();
  System.out.println(it+" - "+Collections.frequency(list.it));
  iter.remove();
}
```

When I have stored the first "apple", I wish to remove other "apple" entries completely from the list so that the next item on the list will be "pear". And when I have stored the first "pear", I wish to remove all duplicate "pear" elements from the list so that the next element will be peach.  When done iterating, I should only have three elements:

```
apple
pear
peach
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just remember the last processed item, and skip processing while the current item is the same as it.

Comment: what language?  what did you try to use?

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you find?  The code you posted removes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the list iterator is a safe way to remove an item from a list while iterating:  The following code example does what you want (no need to create duplicate lists):

```
public class RemoveDuplicates
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("apple");
        list.add("apple");
        list.add("pear");
        list.add("pear");
        list.add("pear");
        list.add("peach");

        System.out.println("Original list: ");
        for (String s : list)
            System.out.println(s);

        String temp = "";
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            String s1 = iterator.next();
            if (temp.equals(s1))
            {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            temp = s1;
        }

        System.out.println("\nProcessed list:");
        for (String s : list)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Original list:
apple
apple
pear
pear
pear
peach

Processed list:
apple
pear
peach
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you have a sorted list.. then you need create another list without the repeated elements, you can't edit a list while you are iterating over it, except if you use `Iterator`

```
List<String> newFruitList = new LinkedList<String>();
String lastFruit = null;
for (String fruit : yourSortedList) {
   if (lastFruit == null || !lastFruit.equals(fruit)) {
       newFruitList.add(fruit);
       lastFruit = fruit;
   }
}
```

By the way, in java definition:

- List: can have repeated elements
- Set: can't have repeated elements

Another thing, i would suggest to you to use another data structure if you need something sorted like a `Tree` that is sorted and faster O(log n)... in your case look for `TreeSet`

Comment: Ah ok. That was what I needed. Since I needed to tally up a frequency, I needed the original list to do so. However, make a second Set with no repeated elements allowed me to output without repeats. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) on the `List` [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) when the current `word` matchs the previous `word`. Like,

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("apple", "apple",
        "pear", "pear", "pear", "peach"));
String str = null;
Iterator<String> iter = al.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String word = iter.next();
    if (!word.equals(str)) {
        str = word;
    } else {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(al);
```

Output

```
[apple, pear, peach]
```